# Microsoft WPF Ribbon Calendar / DatePicker Control

Tags: wpf, calendar, datepicker, ribbon

I am looking for information on how to put a calendar/datepicker control into a WPF Ribbon. Has anyone done this before? What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no DatePicker or Calendar control available with Ribbon controlset.

But you can add the WPF dataPicker control to it, but it will look odd there.  I dont know why you need to add a Calendar or DatePicker control there. 
Ribbons are generally suited for commands.

Answer (score 0):

MS didn't think it was worth adding a calendar in the ribbon. I don't think it was much advantageous anyway. Having said that, it is good to have such a control. This should help

http://chandoo.org/forum/threads/ribbon-datepicker-calendar-control-for-excel-2007-2010.12150/#post-71159